# New query that gets data from 8 other queries into same structure

Tags: sql, group-by, append, ms-access-2010

I have 8 queries that perform calculations and save the results in one of their columns.

The column headers of each query follow the same structure;

```
CompanyYearAssetID, CompanyName, AssetName, Year, DatapointID, NameOfWhateverWasCalculated
```

In each calculation the same DatapointID is assigned to the results. For example;

```
CompanyYearAssetID, CompanyName, AssetName, Year, DatapointID, ReservoirOIL
10001             , CompanyA   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 5
10002             , CompanyB   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 3
10003             , CompanyC   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 0
```

The names of the calculated columns and their DatapointIDs are;

- UnallocatedOIL 105014
- WellworkOIL 105015
- ReservoirOIL 105016
- AnnualShutdownOIL 105017
- FailureUnplannedPlantOIL 105018
- PlantPlannedMaintenanceOIL 105019
- ExportOIL 105020
- MarketOIL 105039

I want to create a query to get all the results into one table ideally using the column headers

```
CompanyYearAssetID, DatapointID, DatapointValue
```

**Does anyone have a clue how i would structure this?**

Just incase you need them here are the 8 query names;

1. PE_Field_UnallocatedOIL
2. PE_Field_WellworkOIL
3. PE_Field_ReservoirOIL
4. PE_Field_AnnualShutdownOIL
5. PE_Field_FailureUnplannedPlantOIL
6. PE_Field_PlantPlannedMaintenanceOIL
7. PE_Field_ExportOIL
8. PE_Field_MarketOIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if both Query 1 and Query 2 return the same data Like this

```
CompanyYearAssetID, CompanyName, AssetName, Year, DatapointID, ReservoirOIL
10001             , CompanyA   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 5
10002             , CompanyB   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 3
10003             , CompanyC   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 0


SELECT * FROM (
   Select * from Query1
   UNION ALL
   Select * from Query2)
```

So the result of this query would then be

```
CompanyYearAssetID, CompanyName, AssetName, Year, DatapointID, ReservoirOIL
10001             , CompanyA   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 5
10002             , CompanyB   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 3
10003             , CompanyC   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 0
10001             , CompanyA   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 5
10002             , CompanyB   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 3
10003             , CompanyC   , Asset1   , 2011, 105014     , 0
```

which You query like a normal table

```
 SELECT * FROM (
       Select * from Query1
       UNION ALL
       Select * from Query2)
where Year = 2011 AND ReservoirOIL > 0
```

Comment: Identical structure of the results from Q1 to Q8 is a must !

Comment: wouldnt that just return all the columns as they appear horizontally?

Comment: Oh i understand, let me try that!

Comment: Do you mind showing me what the WHERE conditions would look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16045/discussion-between-marty-and-magda)